# Prefix matching seach when prefix contains characters treated as whitespaces

Tags: search, query

It is my first post on this forum.

I have the following case. In the search engine there is a property `id` and I have to search by it using the wildcards. The problem is that the `id` can contain the special characters like `-` which are treated by search engine as white spaces.

Example.
`id = ABC-123-XYZ`

--- UPDATE ---

Query test cases:

1. by id, without quotes, not escaped

   - `id:ABC-123*` - OK
   - `id:ABC-123-*` -
     `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.TooComplexQueryException`
   - `id:ABC-123-X*` - OK, but if X replaced by certain characters then `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.TooComplexQueryException`
2. by id, without quotes, minus escaped

   - `id:ABC\-123*` - OK
   - `id:ABC\-123\-*` -    `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.TooComplexQueryException`
   - `id:ABC\-123\-X*` - OK, but if X replaced by certain characters then `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.TooComplexQueryException`
3. by id with quotes:

   - `id:"ABC-123*"` - OK
   - `id:"ABC-123-*"` - OK
   - `id:"ABC-123-X*"` - no results, but should be
4. free text, without quotes, not excaped:

   - `ABC-123*` - `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.TooComplexQueryException`
   - `ABC-123-*` - OK
   - `ABC-123-X*` - `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.TooComplexQueryException`
5. free text, without quotes, minus escaped:

   - `ABC\-123*` - `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.TooComplexQueryException`
   - `ABC\-123\-*` - OK
   - `ABC\-123\-X*` - `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.TooComplexQueryException`
6. free text with quotes

   - `"ABC-123*"` - OK
   - `"ABC-123-*"` - OK
   - `"ABC-123-X*"` - No results, but should be

I can build queries with or without the quotes but search by free text and by property has to work in all combinations. Do you have any idea how to achive this requirement?

I am using Keyword Query Language and I am quering the search engine by webservices.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.toocomplexqueryexception.aspx

Represents an exception that is thrown when there are too many results for this query.

I believe the wildcard `ABC-123-X*` returns too many results.

Comment: There is only few such ids. What I am suspecting is that the query `ABC-123-X*` is tokenized by dashes to the search terms `ABC`, `123` and `X*` and the last term is causing the problem. Is it possible? And how to solve this issue?

Comment: I need to try it out. How if you try ABC-123?

Comment: Then search engine is giving the correct results for this query.

Comment: Have you tried placing the query inside double quotes. Like "ABC-123-X*"?

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope that is clearer now.

Comment: The `-*`at the end will be intepreted as "substract everything", hence the error.

Comment: @RobertLindgren good point. I've added more test cases to the question.